# Importing all reducers, actions into Redux using filename endings. i.e. 'TodoList_Reducers.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I don't like the file structure of:

```
...
reducers/
actions/
components/
...
```

I would much rather store the items in a more logical and easy to edit format, i.e.

```
form
- box
-- radiobox
-- checkbox
- text
-- text
-- textarea
```

This is just easier for me to add components and maintain meaning for each file and it's appropriate tracking. Adding Redux complicates this as such, but allows the same structure.
Example files would be `RadioBox.js, RadioBox_Reducer.js, RadioBox_Actions.js`

How can I do this using some tricky import or method of importing. Of course I want to automate it all so I'm not importing these myself (if possible).

As I'm new to React and Redux, I am also open to suggestions as to why this behaviour is **really bad, like really bad.**

Comment: `app/reducers/appReducer.js` is the same structure as `form/box/radiobox` with the difference of `box` being singular. You're not making any sense.

Comment: So how do I know which reducer goes with which part of my webapp? Or am I making a form of API for the use of a local React app?

Comment: How do you know which box goes with which form :D, usually you name the reducer in some logical way to link it to specific functionality it performs, like `loginReducer.js`

Comment: It's under `Form` here but it would essentially be a `FormCheckbox`. I think I found an answer that is similar to mine. It denotes that reducers and actions should be a different entity and that components should just like to do some set of actions and it's your job to link those actions. So your webapp can do some set of actions and the components are the handles. That's pretty good description I just made myself. I think I rubber duck'd. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly it doesn't make sense to add whole bunch of reducers and actions for simple things like radio-box, checkboxes. You can use local component state for that. Ask yourself if you want to use the checkbox property in multiple components or you want to serialize the state for persistence ? If the answer is no, you do not need redux here.

The way I use redux is to store data like `users`, `products`, `collections`, `orders` etc. which you fetch from api. Also rarely reducers are named after my components or screens but rather logical data in the app. read [this](https://dev.bleacherreport.com/3-things-i-learned-about-working-with-data-in-redux-5fa0d5f89c8b) for more info.

Also you can use [duck-pattern](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be) to avoid that folder structure.

Comment: I know, those were example components. Imagine these radioboxs do insane things that need lots of logic. Or imagine they're another component with heirarchy.